# How do I display a Gif on Windows Phone when calling a StaticResource?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, gif

I am using a RSS feed to display content in my app. Everything works great except gif images. I have read that Silverlight doesn't support the gif file format so I've been trying to use the ImageTools plugin.

There seems to be loads of examples where people click a button and the image displays on the same page but I want to call the image when my listbox is being populated.

Currently this is what I have:

XAML:

```
xmlns:imagetools="clr-namespace:ImageTools.Controls;assembly=ImageTools.Controls"
....
<ListBox x:Name="Weather">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>

                            <imagetools:AnimatedImage Source="{Binding WeatherIcon, Converter={StaticResource DisplayGIF}}" />

                            <TextBlock Name="temperatureBlock" Text="{Binding WeatherTemperatureSummary}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" FontSize="{Binding HeadlineSize}" Foreground="{Binding WeatherTemperatureSummary, Converter={StaticResource StylesAndColours}}" />
                            <TextBlock Name="summaryBlock" Text="{Binding Summary, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmer}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,0,10" FontSize="{Binding SummarySize}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

DisplayGif class:

```
using ImageTools;
using ImageTools.IO;
using ImageTools.IO.Gif;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
public class DisplayGIF : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value.ToString());
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        ExtendedImage image = new ExtendedImage();
        ImageTools.IO.Decoders.AddDecoder<GifDecoder>();
        return image.ToBitmap(); // give error that image is not loaded
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

The above code fails as the image is not yet loaded. Is there a work around to this or even a better/easier way to get the gif images to display?

**EDIT 1**

Based on Ku6opr's answer I have altered my class. When I start my app now it hangs as I suspect I am not managing the threads correctly.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value.ToString());
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        ExtendedImage image = new ExtendedImage();
        ImageTools.IO.Decoders.AddDecoder<GifDecoder>();
        image.SetSource(stream);
        EventWaitHandle Wait = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        image.LoadingCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            Wait.Set();
        };
        Wait.WaitOne();
        return image.ToBitmap();
    }
```

**Edit 2:**

Ok, turns out the gif images I was trying to link to were not hot linkable! The link provided by Ku6opr do work - just make sure that you can actually link to the images from an outside source ;)

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/ASP.NET/Silverlight/imagetools/ImageTools/Controls/ImageConverter.cs.htm

Thanks,

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, it loads image asynchronously. I guess, you need to wait while it completely loaded. `ExtendedImage` maybe has some event (`LoadingCompleted` or something else)

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,         System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value.ToString());
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    ImageTools.IO.Decoders.AddDecoder<GifDecoder>();
    ExtendedImage image = new ExtendedImage();
    image.Source = stream;
    EventWaithandle Wait = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    ExtendedImage.LoadingCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        Wait.Set();
    };        
    Wait.Wait();
    return image.ToBitmap(); // give error that image is not loaded
}
```

While I wrote this code I see that you never assign `Stream` to your image. Check it

**EDIT:**
`ImageTools` already has `ImageConverter` class that works with `Streams`, `Absolute` and `Revative` uri paths. It source code to look inside you can find here: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/ASP.NET/Silverlight/imagetools/ImageTools/Controls/ImageConverter.cs.htm

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. It's sending my down the right path I think ;) I have updated my code with your suggestions but the app hangs when loading now due to the Wait thread block (I think). Any suggestions to work around this?

Comment: Has a `ExtendedImage` `CreateOptions` like `BitmapImage`? If yes, set it to `None`, and `Image` will load synchronously.

Comment: According to the documentation page you can call the load complete method but I'm not sure how to return an object in my Convert method if I do this. http://imagetools.codeplex.com/documentation I'm going to get in touch with the dev for this project as it's just not clear what I'm supposed to do. I'll update this once I've figured it out :)

Comment: `ImageTools` already has `ImageConverter` class that works with Streams, absolute and revative uri paths. Please, look at: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/ASP.NET/Silverlight/imagetools/ImageTools/Controls/ImageConverter.cs.htm

Comment: Please tell, what comment helps you, and I edit my answer accordingly

Comment: Hi Ku6opr, I found the link example you gave worked perfectly. My previous convert code was only trying to do the same thing. The simple example you provided in the link explains what object type to pass back. As I mention in my edit, the website I was pulling the image from was actually blocking hot links so it was never going to work. Went with another website and everything works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually Silverlight for WP7 does not include the necessary codec(s) for displaying gifs.

You should convert the images to a supported format (PNG or JPG).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you know any examples of how to do this when all I have is a link pointing to a file online? Thanks.

Comment: `ImageTools` is for displaying `Gif`. Don't convert anything.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28VS.92%29.aspx GIF is supported on all devices. Am I missing something?